# Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?

Tags: html, margin, css

I tried to add `margin` values on a `div` inside another `div`. All works fine except the top value, it seems to be ignored. But why?

**What I expected:**
[image: What I expected with margin:50px 50px 50px 50px;]

**What I get:**
[image: What I get with margin:50px 50px 50px 50px;]

**Code:**

```css
#outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFCCCC;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

#inner {
  background: #FFCC33;
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    Hello world!
  </div>
</div>
```

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) has no explanation to why `margin` behaves this way.

Comment: did you try floating the inner one?

Comment: hum.. With `float:left;` it works... but why is this needed. I do not want it to float. And why does margin for left/right work?

Answer (score 547, accepted):

You're actually seeing the top margin of the `#inner` element [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) into the top edge of the `#outer` element, leaving only the `#outer` margin intact (albeit not shown in your images). The top edges of both boxes are flush against each other because their margins are equal.

Here are the relevant points from the W3C spec:

> #### 8.3.1 Collapsing margins
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to *collapse*, and the resulting combined margin is called a *collapsed margin*.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse *[...]*

> Two margins are *adjoining* if and only if:
>
> - both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   - top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child

**You can do any of the following to prevent the margin from collapsing:**

> - Float either of your `div` elements
> - Make either of your `div` elements [inline blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519896/106224)
> - Set [`overflow` of `#outer` to `auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519937/106224) (or any value other than `visible`)

**The reason the above options prevent the margin from collapsing is because:**

> - Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).
> - Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.
> - Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

**The left and right margins behave as you expect because:**

> Horizontal margins never collapse.

Comment: Apparently, [you're not the only one to think it's stupid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069921/what-is-the-point-of-css-collapsing-margins)...

Comment: FYI, `Set overflow of #outer to auto (or any value other than visible)` does not work on iOS. So I changed it to `Make either of your div elements inline blocks` and it works well.

Answer (score 133):

Try using `display: inline-block;` on the inner `div`. Like so:

```css
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    display:block;
}
#inner {
    background:#FFCC33;
    margin:50px 50px 50px 50px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that is freaky! Why does that work? What is the logical explanation to why it doesn't work as one would expect. Margin left / right works without `display:inline-block;`. Also set back for when using `display:inline-block;` is that you lose the width of 100% on the div.

Comment: switching it to inline-block forces the browser to reevaluate the size of the div after its placed and other rules are applied.

Answer (score 33):

BoltClock's answer is pretty solid. Here I just want to add several more solutions for this problem.
check this [w3c_collapsing margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). The green parts are the potential thought how this problem can be solved.

**Solution 1**

Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).

that means I can add `float:left` to either `#outer` or `#inner` [demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/liqiang372/55hgnk0b/).

also notice that `float` would invalidate the `auto` in margin.

**Solution 2**

Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.

other than `visible`, let's put `overflow: hidden` into `#outer`. And this way seems pretty simple and decent. I like it.

```
#outer{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FFCCCC;
    margin: 50px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#inner {
    background: #FFCC33;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

**Solution 3**

Margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

```
#outer{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FFCCCC;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: absolute; 
}
#inner{
    background: #FFCC33;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
}
```

or

```
#outer{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FFCCCC;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative; 
}
#inner {
    background: #FFCC33;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

these two methods will break the normal flow of `div`

**Solution 4**

Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

is the same as Enderskill

**Solution 5**

The bottom margin of an in-flow block-level element always collapses with the top margin of its next in-flow block-level sibling, unless that sibling has clearance.

This has not much work to do with the question since it is the collapsing margin between siblings. it generally means if a top-box has `margin-bottom: 30px` and a sibling-box has `margin-top: 10px`. The total margin between them is `30px` instead of `40px`.

**Solution 6**

The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.

This is very interesting and I can just add one top border line

```
#outer{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FFCCCC;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    
}
#inner {
    background: #FFCC33;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
    
}
```

Also, `<div>` is block-level in default, so you don't have to declare it on purpose. Sorry for not being able to post more than 2 links and images due to my novice reputation. At least you know where the problem comes from next time you see something similar.

Answer (score 23):

Not sure why what you have doesn't work, but you can add `overflow: auto;` to the outer `div`.

Answer (score 20):

Not exactly sure why, but changing the inner CSS to

```
display: inline-block;
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 16):

If you add any `padding` to `#outer`, it works. Demo here:

```css
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    display:block;
    padding-top:1px;
}
#inner {
    background:#FFCC33;
    margin:50px 50px 50px 50px;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't answer the "why" (has to be something w/ collapsing margin), but seems like the easiest/most logical way to do what you're trying to do would be to just **add `padding-top` to the outer div**:

```css
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#inner {
    background:#FFCC33;
    margin:0px 50px 50px 50px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

Minor note - it shouldn't be necessary to set a div to `display:block;` unless there's something else in your code telling it not to be block.

Answer (score 5):

## Create new block formatting context

You can use `display: flow-root` on the parent element to prevent margin collapsing through the containing element as it creates new Block Formatting Context.

Changing the value of the overflow property to auto or using flexbox will have the same effect.

https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/VJXjEp

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```css
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    display:table;
}
#inner {
    background:#FFCC33;
    margin:50px 50px 50px 50px;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        Hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Use `padding-top:50px`for outer div. Something like this:

```css
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    height:200px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    display:table;}
```

Note: padding will increase the size of your div. In this case if the size of your div is important, I mean if it must have a specific height. decrease the height by 50px.:

```css
#outer {
    width:500px; 
    height:150px; 
    background:#FFCCCC;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;
    display:table;}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess setting the **position** property of the **#inner** div to **relative** may also help achieve the effect. But anyways I tried the original code pasted in the Question on IE9 and latest Google Chrome and they already give the desirable effect without any modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried !important before all, it will force everything:

```
margin:50px 50px 50px 50px !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a margin collapse issue, then to resolve this you can add
`display: flow-root;` to the parent container.

Aside from that, if *margin-top* is being ignored, try *margin-top* with a negative value, for instance: `margin-top: -2px;`

Comment: This repeats the answer from a year prior that suggests the same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work/66314867#66314867

Answer (score -2):

Just for a quick fix, try wrapping your child elements into a `div` element like this -

```
<div id="outer">
   <div class="divadjust" style="padding-top: 1px">
      <div id="inner">
         Hello world!
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Margin of `inner` div won't collapse due to the padding of `1px` in-between `outer` and `inner` div. So logically you will have `1px` extra space along with existing margin of `inner` div.