# CSS marginTop not working on DIV while marginLeft works

Tags: javascript, css, margin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Let's say I have two DIVs, one inside the other (DIV1 -> DIV2), and I define a marginTop property on the inner DIV, it should move DIV2 within DIV1. Instead it moves DIV1 **and** DIV2 by the # of pixels from the top. Yet marginLeft properly moves DIV2 within DIV1.

```
    // DIV1
    var x = document.createElement("div");
    x.style.width = "200px";
    x.style.height = "200px";
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";

    // DIV2
    var y = document.createElement("div");
    y.style.width = "50px";
    y.style.height = "50px";
    y.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    y.style.marginTop = "10px";
    y.style.marginLeft = "10px"

    document.body.appendChild(x);
    x.appendChild(y);
```

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: @BoltClock Yep seems to be my issue :) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Setting an `overflow: hidden;` on the red `<div>` should correct that

Comment: Yes. I offer an explanation on why this works in my answer to the duplicate question.