# Body height 100% displaying vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Out of curiosity, considering the example below, why does having the margin on the #container div cause a vertical scrollbar to appear in the browser? The container is much smaller in height than the body height which is set to 100%.

I have set the padding and margins to 0 for all elements except the #container. Note that I have deliberately omitted absolute positioning on the #container div. In this case how is the browser calculating the height of the body and how is the margin affecting it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { padding:0; margin:0;}
html, body { height:100%; }
#container
{
  padding:10px;
  margin:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='container'>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Neodymium/kqem5/)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357434/html-body-100-causing-scrollbar-to-appear

Answer (score 82, accepted):

[If you paint the backgrounds of `html` and `body` (giving each its own color)](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/kqem5/3), you'll quickly notice that `body` is being shifted down along with `#container`, and `#container` itself isn't offset from the top of `body` at all. This is a side effect of [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), which I cover in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work/9519933#9519933) (although that answer describes a slightly different setup).

It's this behavior that's causing the scrollbar to appear, since you've declared `body` to have 100% the height of `html`. Note that the actual height of `body` is unaffected, as margins are never included in height calculations.

Comment: Does this mean the heights of elements on a page are calculated starting with the window, then the body, then elements inside/or above the body?  Are all percentages converted into px or pt or em values?

Comment: @TMB: A 100% height on `html` makes it 100% of the viewport (a browser's viewing area), and a 100% height on `body` makes it 100% of its parent, which is `html`. Any percentages that follow are always that of an element's ancestor(s). If you don't set 100% height on `html` or `body` then they behave like any other block element. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#percentage-units for details. %s and ems will eventually all have to be converted to some absolute value during rendering, in order for a browser to know exactly how large or small to measure and render things on screen.

Comment: @TMB: In the case of jsFiddle, the height of the viewport is the same height of the Results pane, since it's basically an iframe.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ah yes. Margin collapsing on nested elements. This now makes sense. The #container div tag is nested within the body tag. It follows the same rules for margin collapsing as any other nested elements would.

Comment: @neodymium: That's right. Both `html` and `body` behave like any other block-level element as well.

Comment: So how should be fixed? By [floating the container as Michel suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22166728/1269037)?

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu: Either that, or any of the other solutions I described in the answer that I link to. Given that the OP constructed this example for illustrative purposes, it's hard to tell what sort of "fix", if any, is appropriate here.

Comment: Since the answer of the author is an enlightening explanation, I would do this just for the record:

`body > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}`

Now the top margin of the very first element in the tag `<body>` wont collapse.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357434/html-body-100-causing-scrollbar-to-appear

Comment: Thank you so much! After struggling with this seemingly simple and stupid problem multiple times, this is the first explanation I found that got me to understand it's actual root. Cheers!

Comment: @Daniel Albuschat: I'm honored!

Answer (score 30):

Based upon @BoltClock♦'s answer, I fixed it by zeroing the margin...

so

```
html,body, #st-full-pg {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
```

works where id "st-full-pg" is assigned to a panel div (which further contained panel-heading and panel-body)

Answer (score 24):

A bit late, but maybe it helps someone.

Adding `float: left;` to `#container` removes the scrollbar, as W3C says:

*•Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).*

Answer (score 11):

```
html,body {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

This worked for me

Comment: if you have a footer it removes it

Answer (score 4):

adding `float:left;` is nice, but will interfere with central horizontal positioning using `margin:auto;`

if you know how big your margin is, you can account for that in your height percentage using calc:

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

browser support is good, but only IE11+
https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Why 50px? Magic number.

Comment: "if you know how big your margin is." I believe is what OP is referring to with the 50px

Comment: Not good if you're supporting mobile devices

Answer (score 2):

```
/*removes default margin & padding*/
html, body{
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

/*sets body height to max; and allows scrollbar as page content grows*/
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: 100vh on body will show a scrollbar when you get overflow in x direction. So it is better to set html and body to 100% height and do not use 100vh at all

Answer (score 2):

**For those who are coming here for an easier to understand answer that even includes code samples, this answer (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122696/3881189)) is for you.**

***No* JavaScript or definite pixel values (such as `100px`) are required, just, pure CSS and percentages.**

If your div is just sitting there on its own, `height: 50%` will mean 50% the height of the body. Normally, the height of the body is zero without any visible content, so 50% of that is just, well, zero.

This is the solution (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609730/3881189)) (uncomment the `background` lines to get a visualisation of the padding):

```css
/* Makes <html> take up the full page without requiring content to stretch it to that height. */

html
{
  height: 100%;
  
  /* background: green; */
}

body
{
  /*
    100% the height of <html> minus 1 multiple of the total extra height from the padding of <html>.
    This prevents an unnecessary vertical scrollbar from appearing.
  */
  height: calc(100% - 1em);
  
  /* background: blue; */
}

/* In most cases it's better to use stylesheets instead of inline-CSS. */
div
{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The above was written so that there would still be the usual padding. You could set the dimensions of the red `div` to `100%` and still see padding on each side/end. If you don't want this padding, use this (although it doesn't look nice, I recommend you stick with the first example):

```css
/* Makes <html> take up the full page without requiring content to stretch it to that height. */

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

/* You can uncomment it but you wouldn't be able to see it anyway. */

/*
html
{
  background: green;
}
*/

body
{
  margin: 0;
  
 /* background: blue; */
}

/* In most cases it's better to use stylesheets instead of inline-CSS */
div
{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution: add padding: 1px 0; to body prevents vertical scrollbars to appear

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. The reason was in the style

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

Once I removed it the problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem fixed before where you put all the contents of `body` in a div called wrap. Wrap's style should be set to `position: relative; min-height: 100%;`. To position `#container` div 50px from the top and left put a div inside wrap with a padding set to 50px. Margins will not work with wrap and the div we just made, but they will work in `#container` and everything inside it.

[here's my fix on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqycuozq/).

Answer (score 0):

you can add non-breaking space into the body tag.

```
<body> &nbsp; <othertags>...</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want to remove the body scrolling add the following style:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue where I was having 2 vertical scroll bars. Setting html to have `overflow: hidden` and leaving body alone fixed that. Both my body and html have `height: 100%`.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by @BoltClock, I tried this and it worked, even when zoom out and in.

`Browser: Chrome 51`

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

I guess `body` was shifted down 20px.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    height: -webkit-fill-available; // Chrome
}

// Firefox
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    body {
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to html and body.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: this solution removes scrollbar completely. even on the pages where scroll is needed

Comment: Also in mobile devices this may create problems, the page will be scrolled when filling forms and everything will be moved from some px.

Answer (score -10):

I found a quick solution: try set height to 99.99% instead of 100%

Comment: There are many reasons why this is a terrible idea, including arbitrary height differences per user window, and that internal rounding methods differ by browser.