# Can't change div height to percent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive div, but for some reason, changing the height to percent just ignores the height. I can only add a fix height.

The div I want to change in the example below is the mainContainer

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.mainContainer{
    width:150%;
    height:550px; /*I want this to be 60% or something*/
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#080808;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.textContainer{ 
    width:55%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    background-color:#666666;
    border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;  /*TL TR BR BL*/
}
#map1 {
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:-15px;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    border-radius:0 15px 15px 0;  /*TL TR BR BL*/
}
.contentBox{
    width:96%;
    height:100%;
    color:#F2F2F2;
    font-size:100%;
    padding-right:3%;
    padding-left:3%;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


<section class="mainContainer">
        <div class="textContainer">
            <div class="intro"> 
                <div class="contentBox">
                             </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
           <div id="map1"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: in order to have a percent-based height ALL parent block level elements need an explicitly declared height. Post markup please.  Also do you ever expect the document (html/body elements) to be TALLER than the viewport/window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent div to the element you are trying to give a height to needs to have as set height in order for the you to give the child element a height %.

```
.wrapper { width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black; }
.content { width: 100%; height: 60%; background-color: red; }
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fy8Kx/

In your example just make sure the parent of `.mainContainer` has a height set to it and then you can make the height `60%`

Comment: Thanks this was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

**For those who are coming here, wondering why they can't see a big red block from something like `<div style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background: red;"></div>`, this answer is for you.**

**Also, *no* JavaScript or definite pixel values (such as `100px`) are required, just, pure CSS and percentages.**

If your div is just sitting there on its own, `height: 50%` will mean 50% the height of the body. Normally, the height of the body is zero without any visible content, so 50% of that is just, well, zero.

This is the solution (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609730/3881189)) (uncomment the `background` lines to get a visualisation of the padding):

```css
/* Makes <html> take up the full page without requiring content to stretch it to that height. */

html
{
  height: 100%;
  
  /* background: green; */
}

body
{
  /*
    100% the height of <html> minus 1 multiple of the total extra height from the padding of <html>.
    This prevents an unnecessary vertical scrollbar from appearing.
  */
  height: calc(100% - 1em);
  
  /* background: blue; */
}

/* In most cases it's better to use stylesheets instead of inline-CSS. */
div
{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The above was written so that there would still be the usual padding. You could set the dimensions of the red `div` to `100%` and still see padding on each side/end. If you don't want this padding, use this (although it doesn't look nice, I recommend you stick with the first example):

```css
/* Makes <html> take up the full page without requiring content to stretch it to that height. */

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

/* You can uncomment it but you wouldn't be able to see it anyway. */

/*
html
{
  background: green;
}
*/

body
{
  margin: 0;
  
 /* background: blue; */
}

/* In most cases it's better to use stylesheets instead of inline-CSS */
div
{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to scale height according to viewport height**,
Use `vh` instead of `%`

```
.mainContainer{height:100vh;}
```

Here it scales as 100% of the viewport.

By the way `width: *any*%;` scales width according to viewport width it can also be written as `vw` but many don't use it because `*any*%` simply works.

Lastly, Don't do this

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Your viewport is already its max height, width.