# HTML Can't Change Height of Div

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a tic tac toe game but for some reason my divs won't change their height.

```css
html {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin:1px;
  width:30%;height:30%;
}
```

```html
<header>Tic Tac Toe</header>
<div id='board'>
  <div class='cell'></div>
  <div class='cell'></div>
  <div class='cell'></div>
</div>
```

The width of the divs is changing fine, but as for the height (which is supposed to be 30% of the screen each) are practically lines.

EDIT: This probably isn't necessary but I feel bad, if you do help out, thank you for taking your time. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you don't have a height to the board and the 30% of almost 0 is... 0.

Add some height to the div with the id of `board`.

Add this to your css:

```
html {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
#board{
 height:300px;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin:1px;
  width:30%;height:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#board { display: block; margin: auto auto; min-height: 100%; }
```

To use percentages your html and body both need to be height 100% then your outer container  (assuming it is #board here) needs to specify min-height to fill the document, and be display type of block.

Comment: Nice, but if you dislike having an unnecessary vertical scrollbar, check out my take on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122696/3881189

Comment: You shouldn’t have a scroll bar unless one of your 100% elements has top or bottom padding/margin/border. So you’d use this technique with a css reset in order to achieve full page with no scroll.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to scale height according to viewport height**,
Use `vh` instead of `%`

```css
     .cell {
          border: 1px solid white;
          margin:1px;
          width:30%;height:30vh;
        }
```

By the way `width: any%;` can scale width freely because width html body (which is serving as a parent in this case)* is always 100%. But the height of the html body starts at 0 so `height: any%;` returns 0px.

*`width:any%;` scales relatively to its parent.

Comment: `width: x%` is not scaled relatively to the viewport, it's scaled relatively to its parent. `width: 100vw` is scaled relatively to the viewport.