# html, body 100% causing scrollbar to appear

Tags: html, css

http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/Wrwdam?editors=110

html:

```
<div class="back">
</div>
```

css:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.back {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/arrow-35.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

The scrollbar on the right displays. I have to have html, body at 100% because of a sticky footer I'm using. Any ideas?

Comment: use `body { overflow:hidden; }`

Comment: html,
body {
    height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: Because you add `margin-top: 50px`, try `padding-top: 50px`

Comment: Add `margin:0;padding:0` to the html and body styles. Also you have an error in the CSS `display:absolute` is not a valid property/value (maybe `display:block` or `position:absolute` but not `display:absolute`)

Comment: @TamilSelvanC what happens when the content is long enough for a scrollbar to actually be needed?

Answer (score 16):

the `body` element has a default `margin: 8px;` in most major browsers so first you have to remove that by resetting the `margin` property on the `body` element

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then, instead of using `height: 100%;` on the body use `min-height: 100%;` so that the body can also *grow beyond 100% height* when used in conjunction with `overflow: hidden;`

Since `min-height` doesn't work if the parent height isn't explicitly set, a `height` attribute has to be added to the `html` element as well.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also, your `div.back` selector has an invalid value on the `display` property. the `display` property accepts `inline`, `inline-block`, `block`, `none`, `flex`, `inline-flex`, `grid` [etc...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) whereas the `position` property accepts `static` (default for every element), `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`. This is not a problem but rather something the browser just ignores as it doesn't understand it.

```
div.back {
    display: absolute; // <------ remove this line
    //... snipped ...
}
```

Comment: "the body element has a default margin: 8px;" This is not strictly speaking true. It all depends what browser you're using.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt true that but if you want to have your website look the same in all browsers, unfortunately you'll have to add it anyways, updating answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

It's partially because the default browser style sheets add some `margins` and/or `padding`. Resetting them to `0` will fix part of it ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyWalkerDesign/ezv1yuew/)).

However you've also got a `div` with some margins applied (`50px`). The way the box-model works will mean you'll need to minus that from your 100%. You can use `calc` if you really need to (or just change it to `padding`):

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

Example using the above code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVPpYK

Example using padding: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMNzqB?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect element, you can see it because of **back** `margin-top` style.

[image]

### Solution

Instead of `margin-top`, use `top`.

And then add `margin: 0`to your HTML/BODY.

Comment: You're right but you're not including the full explanation - the `margin-top` on the `div.back` only affects the `body` tag due to [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)  and it can be fixed using `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` on the `body` element so that it will contain the margin instead

Answer (score 0):

There is another thought, even though some of these answers work.  Set the body to have a `margin` of `0` and `float` the `div` to the `left`.

[Example - Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxepge)

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; }

div.back { 
    float: left; 
    margin-top: 50px; 
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url('http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/arrow-35.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `overflow`.

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
}
```