# Why isn't 'margin-top' property working?

Tags: css, margin

I am aware about the concept of 'margin-collapse'. But , why am I not able to see 10 px margin on the top of the first box [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2f4Kz/1/). The top box(which has the id 'first') should have 10px margin above it. If this is not the correct wat to get it, then what is it? And, why this doesn't work.

CSS:

```
#Main{
background-color: gray;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;  
}


.box{
position:relative;
height: 60px;
width: 175px;
background: black;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Main"> 
    <div id="first" class="box"></div>
    <div id="second" class="box"></div>
    <div id="third" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I know one way could be that we can give 10px padding to the parent div. But then why doesn't this thing work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Comment: @BoltClock♦ no, that is not the answer to my question. I didnt provide any margin to the parent element. So, how can they collapse?

Comment: Oh, I read it wrong. The same principle applies though, *even if the parent element has zero margin*.

Comment: @BoltClock♦ How can it be? How will the margins collapse when there is no margin being provided to the outer parent div?

Comment: It comes from the child element.

Comment: @BoltClock♦ And then how can it be correted? By proving 'padding-top' to the parent div or by proving 'top' to 'box class'. Is there no way to correct it using 'margin' property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how browsers interperit the code. It does not output the expected result which would be a 10px gap between the top of the child and the outter parent. You could add `padding-top` to the parent, alternatively you could assign `overflow:auto;` to your main div.

DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/2f4Kz/4/

```
#Main {
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Another way around this is to add a transparent border around the main div (stops margin collapsing)

```
#Main {
        background-color: gray;
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        border: thin solid transparent;
    }
```

The third a final option (to my knowledge) is to stop the margin collapsing by setting  `padding-top: 1px; margin-top: -1px;` to the parent div

```
#Main {
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px` in your code moves the *"Main"* box as well.
If you want to move the box with id *"first"* only, use `position:relative; top: 10px;`

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/2f4Kz/2/)
edit: I don't know to say for sure why this happens but my guess is it is because the `display` of the *"Main"* box is `block` by default. 
When you use `display: inline-block;` on the *"Main"* box, the problem is fixed. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/2f4Kz/3/))

Comment: can  you please explain that how 'margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px' moves the main box?