# Why is CSS style for top and bottom margins not applied to inner div

Tags: css, margin

Curious why the top and bottom margins of 10px are not applied to the inner div in the snippet below.  If I set the inner display property to "inline-block" it applies the top/bottom margins as expected.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/spn3V/2/)

HTML:

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        My content...
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.outer {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}   
.inner {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 600px;
    margin:10px;
    display: block; /* No top, bottom margins applied.  Does apply them with "inline-block".  Why? */ 
}
```

Comment: Explained pretty well over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .inner top margin is [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

An easy fix is to make the outer `display:inline-block` You should put `padding:10px` on the outer and no margin on the inner.