# Give a margin top to a inline level block element

Tags: css

It is supposed you can not give a margin top to a inline level element, but I dont have problems here: http://jsfiddle.net/FYUtm/ why?

```
<label style="margin-left: 40px; display: inline">foobar</label>
```

Comment: without seeing you code, maybe you have a collapsing margin issue.

`margin-bottom` on the previous element, and `margin-top` on the element you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that margin-LEFT, I voted to close the question

Comment: no. don't close the question. maybe other people might benefit from it.

Comment: You don't need to vote to close, you can just delete the question. @AliCarikcioglu benefit from it in what way? It's a typo as the OP has pointed it, there is no problem to solve here.

Comment: there is an answer below, that people might benefit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical margins do not affect inline elements, as stated in the [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) specification, section 8.3:

> Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but **vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements.**