# Trying to center a div within a container div

Tags: css, html, center

Here's my CSS:

```
#main {
  background: #eae8dc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 790px;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#header-container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 118px;
  width: 648px;
  background: #9ed5de;
  margin: 11px auto;
}
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="main">
   <header>
     <h1 id="header-container">
     </h1>
   </header>
</div>
```

This question was helpful in fixing my margin issue, but now I can't seem to center the header container.  [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text-align should help you center it:

```
#main {
  background: #eae8dc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 790px;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
#header-container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 118px;
  width: 648px;
  background: #9ed5de;
  margin: 11px auto;
}
```

Here's the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RBkmv/

Comment: CSS is so un-intuitive :(.  Thanks, that definitely worked but will it center every element within #main?  I'd like to avoid that if possible

Comment: Yes it will - If this is not what you want, you'll need to rethink your approach, or rely on a 50% left margin, which is ill advised

Comment: What is the canonical or typical way to do organize the html & css in order to achieve this?

Comment: I would highly suggestion learning the order of precedence for CSS http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence - this is a pretty good page for explaining it. From there, you can form your own ways of doing it. I'm typically hesitant to advice people of "canonical or typical" ways of doing things unless there truly is a right and wrong way to achieve the goal

Answer (score 1):

This is bad practice. You should style you `header` element and not your `h1` element.
[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/M2HTX/)

```
#main {
  background: #eae8dc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 790px;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
header {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 118px;
  width: 648px;
  background: #9ed5de;
  margin: 11px auto;
}
```

This way, your CSS code works.

Comment: Your JSFiddle still has it on the H1

Comment: No, the style is for the header element.