# Unexplained Space Between Divs

Tags: html, css

HTML and CSS below. Div id "black" seems to be pushing a space between itself and the "brown" div above it. When I remove the "black" div, the excess space disappears. I have all margins and padding at zero. Can't sort out what's causing this. ANy suggestions are appreciated.

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000000;
}
#greyWrapper {
  background-color: #303030;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: auto;
}
#Brown {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #644015;
}
#Brown ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Brown ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#black {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="greyWrapper">
  <div id="Brown">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Portfolios</li>
      <li>Team</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="black">
    <p>Grab Your Copy Of</p>
    <p>The Premium Quality PSD Template</p>
    <p>For free Download</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you make us a fiddle or code snippet?

Comment: The space is caused by the margin on the first `<p>` inside `div#black`. This is known as [collapsing margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fz840wh2/ looks fine to me (Chrome)

Comment: Do a css element style reset before applying your style on elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable margin-collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the automatic margin-before on the `<p>` tag that is applied by most browsers. Set:

```
#black p {
    margin: 0
}
```

and you'll see it go away.

Comment: What is "margin-before"? What if the OP wants some margin on the `<p>` tags?

Comment: Darn it Joshua, you beat me.

Comment: NickBailey lol, showdev - It's Chrome custom property. I more specifically meant margin-top but the browser-specific version for the automatically-added margin in Chrome is margin-before.

Answer (score 3):

Your `p`s have a margin and this margin extends beyond the limits of the `#black` div and "push against" the `#brown` div. There's a good explanation in [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

You can either:

- Put a border around `#black`. The border will force the div to expand so that it contains all of the margins of the children.

```css
#black {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

or

- Remove the top margin of the topmost paragraph

```css
#black > p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That was it - default margin on the <p> tag. Set that to zero and space closed up. Thank you! Now... how do i mark this as "answered?...

Comment: <p> tag margin. Yes! Thank you.