# Why does a 1px border cancel out a 100px margin-top and kills a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, border, margin

This doesn't yet make sense to me. What am I missing?

[image: Uncomment the border to kill the scrollbar]

The code is below and [on Codepen](http://codepen.io/dandv/pen/oXqpgv?editors=110).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  /* uncomment the border to kill the scrollbar! */
/* border: 1px solid green; */
}

.middle div {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div>Text</div>
</div>
```

`box-sizing: border-box;` doesn't make any difference. Adding a [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) causes the [vertical margins to not collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work/9519933#9519933), but what exactly is going on?

- with border: no scrollbar
- *without border*, the two top margins collapse, so there should be *less* vertical space required, yet we get a vertical scrollbar on the full-height `body`.

Answer (score 8):

This is due to margin collapsing:

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

When `.middle` does not have a `border` the `margin` applied to `.middle div` ends up outside of it effectively making `body` have `height: 100vh;` and `margin-top: 100px;`. This is what causes the scrollbar.

With the `border` on `.middle` the `margin` is contained within `.middle` so `body` just has `height: 100vh;` and no scrollbar.

As confirmation of this, you will find that you get the same outcome if you were to add a `border` to `body` instead.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.middle {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  /* uncomment the border to kill the scrollbar! */
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
}
.middle div {
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div><a href="https://iDoRecall.com">Text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "When `.middle` does not have a border the margin applied to `.middle div` ends up outside of it effectively making `body` have `height: 100vh;` and `margin-top: 100px;`." - this. Whoever came up with this idea at @3C deservesto never have personal space again.

Comment: Haha, yeah, collapsing margins have been the cause of many head scratching moments, although I guess there is method to their madness!