# In CSS, the "margin" of element has no effect for the "height" of its parent?

Tags: html, css

Following is the snippet ([demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrtfhyky/))

```css
#inner {
    background-color: yellow;    
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#outer {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

As can be seen in the demo, the `#inner` element has a `margin-bottom`.

I expected the height of `#outer` will be large enough to include the outline of `#inner` margin. And the output will have **a red bar below the yellow bar**.

However, I found the `#outer`'s height is not changed at all though I added the rule `margin-bottom: 50px` for `#inner`.

Does anyone have ideas about this?  And is there a way to ensure the content area of parent is large enough to hold the outline of its child's margin?

Also, apart from giving a hack solution, it would be great if the answer can include some explanation or links to related document/article. And why is the margin rule designed like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is the [*collapsing margins* problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed)
>   into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined
>   into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

Out of the three cases, yours is the case of collapsing margins between parent and child elements.

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or
>   max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the
>   margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The
>   collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

If you add another element just after your parent `div` you will see that the margin ends up outside of it. The snippet below, shows you the collapsed margin:

```css
#inner { background-color: yellow; margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px; }
#outer { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<p>You can see the collapsed margin above this text outside of the parent div.</p>
```

Here is the reference from the specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

---

#### How to fix this?

The solution is given in the quoted ref text itself above. Just apply any one of these to your parent `div` - `border`, `padding`, `height`, `min-height`, or `max-height`.

Easiest way to fix this would be to add a border to your outer `div`:

```
#outer { background-color: red; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Better still, apply padding to the parent `div` instead of the margin on inner one.

```
#outer { background-color: red; padding-bottom: 50px; }
```

**Examples:**

*Fiddle (with border): http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rrtfhyky/1/*

*Fiddle (with padding): http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rrtfhyky/2/*

**Snippet (with padding):**

```css
#inner { background-color: yellow; margin-left: 50px; }
#outer { background-color: red; padding-bottom: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<p>Some text that follows.</p>
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, though a border seems like a rather intrusive fix. A more natural solution would be to change the inner element margin to outer element padding. There are a number of other ways to block margin collapse, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work/9519933#9519933), though most of them have pretty adverse effects on layout so it's not just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, just add `overflow: auto` to `#outher` div and it will fix the parents height

```css
#inner {
    background-color: yellow;    
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#outer {
    overflow: auto;   /* ADDED */
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation from @Abhitalks but this was the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
Add This CSS

#inner {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this common "bug", what I would do if I were you is changing the margin into padding and put it to the outer div:

1. My solution:

   ```
   #inner {
       background-color: yellow;    
   }
   #outer {
       background-color: red;
       padding-left: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 50px;
   }
   ```

Also there are 3 other possible fixes:

2. By @Jenti Dabhi is the add the `display:inline-block` to the `#inner` div:

   ```
   #inner {
       background-color: yellow;
       margin-left: 50px;
       margin-bottom: 50px;
       display: inline-block;
   }
   ```
3. By @Chris is to add `overflow: auto` to the `#outer` div:

   ```
   #outer {
       overflow: auto;
       background-color: red;
   }
   ```
4. By @Abhitalks is to add a `border` to your `#outer` div:

   ```
   #outer {
       background-color: red; border: 1px solid gray;
   }
   ```

Comment: You need to indent your code blocks with 8 spaces per line in a list.

Answer (score 0):

give a border to outer div :

```css
#inner {
    background-color: yellow;    
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
     
}
#outer {
    background-color: red;
    border:1px solid white;
      
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a Typography concept, 
generally, vertical margins of adjacent elements collapse!

Have a look at this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)