# div elements not working

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements and `nav > nav_1`. When i add a `margin-top:20px;` to `nav`, `nav` goes down `20px`according to body which is correct.
But when i add this `margin-top:20px;`to `nav_1`,`nav_1` goes down `20px` with `nav` according to body.
why ? `nav_1` element of `nav` and it should move according to `nav`.
In that question im looking for an explanation

```css
.nav {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.nav .nav_1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav_1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no margin in your code example

Comment: @messerbill but it isnt a quesiton to fix

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work

Answer (score 4):

This is one case of "margin collapse" mechanism. In brief margin of parent and child elements are collapsed into single margin of size equals max of their corresponding margins. There are several ways to disable such a behaviour, e.g. adding border or padding to parent element. You can read more about that mechanism at [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `padding` on `nav` and remove `margin` on `.nav .nav_1`

**or**

you can add `display:inline-block` in `.nav .nav_1`

```css
 .nav {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;

}
.nav .nav_1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav_1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: padding doesnt fix it but i think this is about adding "display:inline-block;",

Answer (score -1):

Further to @Paul Kozlovitch answer, to fix this you can set the the parent `display:inline-block` (or `float` etc).

```css
.nav {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.nav .nav_1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav_1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm i tought div elements already a block...thx

Comment: `block`, not `inline-block`.. glad to help ;)