# Why does margin-bottom show as margin-top?

Tags: html, css

I try to add margin-bottom on a div inside parent but it show as parent's margin-top. Why?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
  border: 1px solid #F68004;
}

#content{
  background-color: #0075CF;
  height: 100px;
}

#box{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

**What I expected**:

[image]

**What I get**:

[image]

**Update:**

> I can fix this but i have no idea why that code not work? can someone explain?

**Update 2:**

It look like most answer say that it because of margin collapse and my question duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work). But please note that i set **margin-bottom** but NOT **margin-top**. I also read about collapsing margins and i can not found any rule say that margin-bottom can become margin-top. Can anyone point me out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work

Comment: I has updated my question again, thank you!

Comment: @MinhHoang If your issue solved. You should accept any of the answer which solve your issue, by clicking on right symbol.

Comment: @ketan my issue is not solved yet.

Comment: @Pete I put margin-bottom but not margin-top

Answer (score 9):

Give `margin-bottom: 50px;` to `#content` instead of `#box` Because you have given height to `#content` div and here margin collapse.

[Here it is explain with example](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/)

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7drzfb9x/)**

Answer (score 5):

The reason why the margin appears to be on top is due to [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing):

**Parent and first/last child**
If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

If you add add a transparent border to your parent div (`#content`) then your margin will behave:

```css
#wrapper{
  border: 1px solid #F68004;
}

#content{
  border:1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #0075CF;
  height: 100px;
}

#box{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height:10px; background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want the white space at the bottom like in your expected image, just add  `padding-bottom:50px` to `#wrapper`

**Update**

Why the `margin-bottom` is causing `margin-top`: As the collapsing margin is moving outside your parent div, it becomes margin bottom of the element outside the parent (which is the top border of `#wrapper`) - which pushes your `#content` div down (making it look like margin-top)

Comment: As your update, if i set margin-top to #box instead of margin-bottom then it will becomes margin-top of top border of #wrapper right? So why i got same result? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the jsFiddle with your expectations:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y277r5zL/)

as you wanted the yellow border be around the whole content so it was better to extend your wrapper height.

```css
#wrapper{
  border: 1px solid #F68004;
  height: 150px;
}

#content{
  background-color: #0075CF;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gvLeto9b/1/)**

Instead of setting height to `#content`, you can use it for `#box`

```
#content {
  background-color: #0075CF;        
}

#box {margin-bottom: 50px; height: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
#content {
  background-color: #0075cf;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#box{
  /* margin-bottom: 50px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give the margin to #content instead of #box.
And if you want to give margin to #box only. Try to give it with minus value i.e. -(50+div height)
If div #box height is 150px then use-

```css
#box {
      margin-bottom: -200px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">       
    </div>
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Solution 2:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="content">
      <div id="box"></div>
   </div>
</div>


  <style>
    #wrapper{
    border: 1px solid #F68004;
    height: 150px;
   }

#content{
   background-color: #0075CF;
   height: 100px;
 }

#box{
    /*margin-bottom: 50px;*/
  }
 </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
  border: 1px solid #F68004;
}

#content{
  background-color: #0075CF;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```