# Why is Margin-Top Not Moving Something?

Tags: html, css

margin-top seems to not be working for me.  Margin-left is working fine.  Howeever, when I use margin-top nothing moves.  Not even if I set it to some absurd number.

My HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pricepages.css" media="screen" />
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="{{var protoHost}}img/Internet.jpg" class="col-xs-0 img-responsive"/>
      <div class="contactspacer"> </div>
        <div class="DSLBlurb">
          <a href="Internet/DSL">Home DSL</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.DSLBlurb {
  background-color: #277FD8;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.DSLBlurb a {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

What could the issue possibly be?  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a>` default CSS value is `inline` so try changing it to `inline-block` or `block` whatever suits you better.

So:

```
.DSLBlurb a {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It fixed the issue.  You get one upvote and one accept!

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your a tag position relative & top attribute like this:

```
color: white;
/* margin-top: 10px !important; */
margin-left: 16px;
position: relative;
top: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you dont even need margin you can just say:

```
//Dont use pixels use % different screens have different needs.

.DSLBlurb a {
  color: white;
  top: 10%;
  left: 16%;
}
```