# Why margin-top can't work after deleting `border:1px solid red`?

Tags: html, css

This is CSS1 code.

```css
div.footer{
background:url('http://i.imgur.com/rfC0Ntb.jpg') repeat-x;
height:88px;
margin:0 auto;
width:400px;
border:1px solid red;
}
div.footer p{
margin-top:40px;
text-align:center; 
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="footer"><p>Copyright&copy; 2013 service center</p></div>
</body>
```

In css1 40px was added :
1. at the top of box `div.footer p`.
2.in the box `div.footer`.
This is css2 code.

```css
div.footer{
background:url('http://i.imgur.com/rfC0Ntb.jpg') repeat-x;
height:88px;
margin:0 auto;
width:400px;
}
div.footer p{
margin-top:40px;
text-align:center; 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="footer"><p>Copyright&copy; 2013 service center</p></div>
</body>
```

In css2 ,`border:1px solid red` was removed from `div.footer` and `div.footer p` ,it result in
1.40px was added at the top of box `div.footer`
2.out of box `div.footer`
In my opnion there maybe no different effect between css1 code and css2 code,`border:1px solid red` is to draw a region only,why it can result in the differences?
I want to know the reason,why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `margin-collapsing`, without border there is nothing to contain the margin of child element. Instead of border you can also fix that with `padding` or `overflow: auto`

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent

```css
div.footer {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rfC0Ntb.jpg') repeat-x;
  height: 88px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 1px;
}
div.footer p {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Copyright&copy; 2013 service center</p>
</div>
```

```css
div.footer {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rfC0Ntb.jpg') repeat-x;
  height: 88px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.footer p {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Copyright&copy; 2013 service center</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
http://codepen.io/yash02/pen/xVMVEY
Play with the css in the code and try commenting the padding and the margin as you asked in the question. Padding was added by me.

Actually the margin you had set which is `40px` is taking the margin from top of the page not the div.

Padding will solve the problem