# CSS- margin-top not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, margin

```css
#modal {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  //border: thin red solid;
  height: 500px;
}
#category_main {
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin red solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div id="category_main"></div>
</div>
```

When I run then , margin-top is not working. the div `category_main` has come down with the div in which it is presented. I don't want that white part. instead of , only that red bordered box should be affected to `margin-top`. [image]

Thank You.

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of applying `margin-top` to `#category_main`, you should apply `padding-top` to `#modal`, as the former leaves a gap but the latter includes the same:

```
#modal{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    //border: thin red solid;
    height: 500px;
    padding-top: 5%;
}
```

See the demo [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/ymuyhbax/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent so that the parent gain its real height you specified..

Here is the **snippet**

```css
#modal{
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        /*border: thin red solid;*/
        height: 500px;
        overflow:hidden;
}

  #category_main{
                width: 75%;
                height:200px;
                border: thin red solid;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 15%;
            }
```

```html
<div id="modal">
    <div id="category_main"></div>
</div>
```

**NOTE**

In css comments should be passed in between `/*.......*/` this, not `//....`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this the wrong way around. you want to put padding on the outer div.

```
 padding-top: 5%;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css for `#modal`,

> vertical-align:middle;
>
> display: table-cell;

```css
#modal {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  //border: thin red solid;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#category_main {
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin red solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div id="category_main"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Really if u dont want the white space as you desired, just add padding:5% to the main div..May b this will solve your problem

```css
#modal {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  //border: thin red solid;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 5%;
}
#category_main {
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin red solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div id="category_main"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#modal {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  //border: thin red solid;
  height: 500px;
  padding:5%;
}
#category_main {
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  border: thin red solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div id="category_main"></div>
</div>
```