# Difference between p and div as block elements

Tags: html, css

I have two sample programs as follows:

Program A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<p style="float:left">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
<p>This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text.</p>
```

Program B:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="float:left">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
<div>This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text.</div>
```

I have a few clarifications :

a) Although `<p>` and `<div>` are block elements , why is there a difference in display where `<div>` is behaving a perfect inline-block type which is acceptable .

But why is the behaviour of `<p>` element different here ?

Comment: **The <p> tag defines a paragraph.** and **The <div> tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.**

Comment: Inspect the elements' default CSS in your browser's element inspector. They have different default styles, most notably `p` has a margin. Because they're different elements, used for different purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<p>` element has default margins. Furthermore, the non-floating `<p>` element's top margin [collapses with the `<body>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work/9519933#9519933), while the floating `<p>` element's margin does not. This is what results in the two paragraphs being misaligned: the floating `<p>`'s outer (margin) edge is aligned with the inner (border) edge of `<body>`, while the inner edges of both the non-floating `<p>` and `<body>` are aligned with each other.

`<div>` has no such default margins, so the two `<div>` elements align just fine.

The others talk about semantic differences between the two elements — while that isn't directly pertinent here since this is a matter of CSS and not HTML, it does explain *why* `<p>` comes with default margins in the first place: because paragraphs are individual runs of text that are visually separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers have default CSS values for elements like p, such as margin which makes your two versions render differently.

That's why it is common to use CSS files like [Normalize](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) or [Reboot](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/reboot/) to reset all browsers to the same value and build from there.