# CSS margin vh not working right

Tags: html, css

```css
    #grenze
    {
     background: green;
     height: 96vh;
     width: 96vh;
    }
    
    #baukasten
    {
     background: white; 
     height: 86vh; 
     width: 86vh; 
     margin: 5vh;
     border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;  
     overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div id="grenze">
   <div id="baukasten">   
   </div>
</div>
```

Margin works only to left but not to top, I tried with different browsers and it's always the same. What could be the problem here? Is it a bug?

**EDIT:**

I can't use padding on `grenze` instead because

```
            $( ".dragresize" ).draggable({
                containment: "#grenze"
            });
```

Won't do what I need

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work

Comment: Do you really need the full explanation? I could do it the way Andrey Fedorov suggested but it wont work with                     $( ".dragresize" ).draggable({
                        containment: "#grenze"
                    }); the right way. I just want margin to work how it supposed to

Comment: Hi , try to write display:inline-block on #baukasten --- children element

Comment: Thanks display:inline-block did the trick. God I HATE CSS !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#grenze {
  background: green;
  height: 96vh;
  width: 96vh;
  padding: 5vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#baukasten {
  background: white;
  height: 86vh;
  width: 86vh;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="grenze">
  <div id="baukasten">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#grenze {
  background: green;
  height: 96vh;
  width: 96vh;
}

#baukasten {
  background: white;
  height: 86vh;
  width: 86vh;
  transform: translate(5vh, 5vh);
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="grenze">
  <div id="baukasten">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't need padding, the stuff that I'm doing will only work with margin

Comment: @AnneSchwarz why? explain the initial problem

Comment: Ok. I added second option. )

Comment: That works :D just like adding display:inline-block to baukasten

Answer (score 4):

This is known as [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) and is a *feature* of CSS, not a bug.

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance **to separate the
> margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block**, or
> no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height
> to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its
> last child, **then those margins collapse**. The collapsed margin ends up
> outside the parent.

Go ahead and inspect your element and you'll see the margin is there, and it has indeed fallen outside of it's parent.