# margin-top is not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a popup at the bottom right corner of my web in WordPress.

The popup is working properly, but I have 2 lines of text, a message and a button. Everything was okay since I wanted to put a margin-top in the button because the button was covering the text.

Here you can see the HTML code and the CSS.

```css
#corner-slider {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 369px;
  border: 1px solid #2d93f1;
  background: #2d93f1;
}

#corner-slider.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#corner-slider .close {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1002;
  right: 24px;
  top: 10px;
}

.popup-button {
  padding: 8px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 45px;
  margin-top: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id="corner-slider">
  Do you want to stay here?
  <br />
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="popup-button">Click me!</a>
</div>
```

So, why is margin-top not working? What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Try applying `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to your `.popup-button`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this CSS margin-top style not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519841/why-does-this-css-margin-top-style-not-work)

Comment: Or why not just use a <p> tag for your text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor element `<a>` is an inline element. Change its `display` type to `inline-block` or `block`:

```css
#corner-slider {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 369px;
  border: 1px solid #2d93f1;
  background: #2d93f1;
}

#corner-slider.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#corner-slider .close {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1002;
  right: 24px;
  top: 10px;
}

.popup-button {
  padding: 8px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="corner-slider">
  Do you want to stay here?
  <br />
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="popup-button">Click me!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP didn't use a button element - he used an anchor element - I took the liberty to update your post :)

Comment: @Danield Thanks, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

button is not stable, just add `disply:inline-block` or `float:left`

```css
#corner-slider {
position: fixed;
z-index: 10000;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 15px;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 60px;
height: 120px;
width: 369px;
border: 1px solid #2d93f1;
background: #2d93f1;
}
#corner-slider.hidden {
display: none;
}
#corner-slider .close {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 16px;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 1002;
right: 24px;
top: 10px;
}
.popup-button {
padding: 8px 30px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 45px;
margin-top: 10px;
display: inline-block; /* newly added */
}
```

```html
<div id="corner-slider">
  Do you want to stay here?
  <br />
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="popup-button">Click me!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty much identical to [ovokuro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45077343/3316645).

Comment: @domdom you commented here when i was adding snippet , i don't see your comment before

Comment: It is completely fine that you turned my comment into an answer; I just wanted to make you aware that someone else (ovokuro) already submitted the same answer as you - some 40 seconds earlier.

Comment: What do you mean by "Button is unstable"?

Comment: i mean the button is not blocked element

Answer (score 0):

i made some changes in your code just have a look in the below code, just place the text in the div and add a css of margin-bottom:15px;

```
<style>
  #corner-slider {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:10000;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  width:369px;
  border:1px solid #2d93f1;
  background:#2d93f1;
  }
  #corner-slider.hidden{
  display:none;
  }
  #corner-slider .close{
  position:absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:1002;
  right:24px;
  top:10px;
}

.popup-button {
  padding: 8px 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff; 
  border-color: #ffffff; 
  border-radius: 45px;
  margin-top: 240px;
}
/*--------------- new css ----------*/
.small-area
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
<div id="corner-slider">
 <div class="small-area">Do you want to stay here?</div>
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="popup-button">Click me!</a>
</div>
```